# Prove a "distance" is a metric between vector spaces

Tags: matrices, vector-spaces, metric-spaces, svd, grassmannian

In a paper by Alan Edelman, ["The geometry of algorithms with orthogonality
constraints"](http://www-math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/geometry_of_algorithms.pdf) (page 35 ), there are several definitions to the notation "distance" between vector spaces on the Grassmanian.
Let Y1 and Y2 be orthonormal matrices,
I need an answer of "true" or "false" if the distance

$$d_{cf}(Y_1,Y_2)= \min_{O_1 ,O_2 \in O_p}\|Y_1\cdot O_1-Y_2\cdot O_2\|_{\text{Frobenius}}$$

defines a metric. Does it satisfy the triangle inequality?

Although I succeded to prove that

$$d_cf(Y_1 , Y_2)\leq \sqrt{2}(d_cf(Y_1 , Y_3)+d_cf(Y_3 , Y_2))$$

I still think the answer is "no", because I know that

$$d_cf(Y_1 , Y_2) = \|Y_1\cdot U- Y_2 \cdot V\|_{\text{Frobenius}}$$

where $U(\textbf{cos($\Theta$))}V^T$ is the singular value decomposition
of $Y_1^{T}Y_2 $ and  $ \Theta$ is the diagonal matrix of principal angles.

Comment: What is the meaning of $O_p$ ??

Comment: The group of orthogonal matrices

Comment: So $O_1$ and $O_2$ are orthogonal matrices. What are $Y_1$ and $Y_2$? Are they arbitrary matrices? And $\|\cdot\|_2$ denotes the spectral norm?

Comment: P.S. Your link goes to a different paper, "Multiscale Computation with Interpolating Wavelets".

Comment: http://www-math.mit.edu/~edelman/publications/geometry_of_algorithms.pdf

Comment: Thank you for noticed

Comment: @Rahul Y1 Y2 arbitrary matrices of full degree (please try to open the paper in page 35)

Comment: Y1 Y2 are orthonormal matrices